# Opportunity Forces One Record Type

Tags: page-layout, record-type

Problem: When creating an opportunity, I select my desired record type, but the page layout provided to me is not assigned to that record type. Why?

**EDIT:** In addition to the steps below, I also tried changing the default record type (previously it was set to "A", I changed it to "B".) This did not change anything.

More Info: Here are the steps I have taken:

1. New Opportunity
2. Select Record Type "B"
3. Page layout "A" is presented (I have verified that the page layout "A" is assigned to record type "A" and page layout "B" is assigned to record type "B" for all profiles)
4. If I create the opportunity (in page layout "A") the opportunity is successfully created, and I can see on the page layout it has been assigned to record type "A", even though I selected "B".
5. I can change the record type to "B" once I have created the record. Once I have saved the opportunity as record type "B", the correct page layout ("B") displays.

Why would this happen? I'm doing this as a system administrator, I have access to both record types, and I have confirmed that the page layouts are assigned correctly. For some reason it just won't let me CREATE an opportunity with this new record type.

Answer (score 0):

Someone had assigned a controller extension which was overriding the default "new" behavior. Because I had seen the OOB "select a record type" page, I had forgotten that a controller extension was an option here.